# geth/parity PoA consensus algorithms - did someone try to measure the performance?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, poa, clique

PoA consensus algorithms are an acceptable choice in public/private permissioned networks.

**[Q]**: Did someone try to setup a benchmark for measuring the performance of existing PoA implementations in parity and geth?

Possible parameters for the measurements could be:

- block gas limits
- block times
- authority (sealer) node count
- transaction sizes
- ...

Comment: I did some tests on my own with geth clique and two sealers on two different machines. I was able to run ~4000tx/s (simple ether transfer). Which is not that bad at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, have a look at my current question: [parity TPS optimization - please help](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/58521/parity-tps-optimization-please-help) = I could not really accelerate parity yet.  For now, geth looks MUCH faster.

Feel free to run your own benchmarks, it is easy with [chainhammer & chainreader](https://gitlab.com/electronDLT/chainhammer). Please report back what you find out. Thanks.