# parity TPS optimization - please help

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, clique, benchmark, aura

## how to accelerate parity PoA ?

I have been

### benchmarking different Ethereum clients

with a focus on their PoA capabilities. [Current results are](https://gitlab.com/electronDLT/chainhammer/blob/master/reproduce.md#results):

**56 TPS with parity aura

322 TPS with geth clique**

when run on an Amazon AWS *t2.xlarge* machine.

I have no good explanation for this huge discrepancy. I do not think parity is that much slower, however I haven't found those optimizing configuration choices yet, which would push it further.

How to use my "chainhammer" benchmarking tool? Either

(1) clone the [ready-made Amazon AWS machine described here](https://gitlab.com/electronDLT/chainhammer/blob/master/reproduce.md#readymade-amazon-ami) (8 minutes), or
(2) follow [these precise instructions](https://gitlab.com/electronDLT/chainhammer/blob/master/reproduce.md#how-to-replicate-the-results) how to install everything (~20 minutes?)

Why I am asking here?
The [parity team has no time for this now](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/9393#issuecomment-418689243) - so I hope any other parity expert can help us.

TL;DR: Help us to speed up **parity PoA**, with some clever commandline switch choices. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar problem a while ago, there was a bottleneck on the time it took transactions to reach the mempool, this was due to the way I was sending them and the fact that they were being signed at node level. That added a pretty big overhead.

The solution I found is to replicate a more real environment.

1. Sign all transactions locally (pre-signed them)
2. Send them to the node asynchronously (don't wait for the receipt) best way I found was sending signed transactions via [RPC calls](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-eth-module#eth_sendrawtransaction)
3. Send them to different validator nodes (This last one will yield the smallest improvement)

After that, you should see a more linear (for a while) relation between the block time and block gas limit vs TPS

Good luck!